# I only get basic info of Facebook user, but I need more

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

This is how I call `login-callback.php`:

```
$permissions = ['email', 'user_likes', 'user_hometown'];
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost:1234/fbtest/login-callback.php', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
```

And here's my logged in action inside `login-callback.php`:

```
if (isset($accessToken)) {
  // Logged in!
  $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

 $response = $fb->get('/me');
  $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();


  print_r($userNode);
echo 'data: ' . $userNode['name'];
echo '<br>';

}
```

Output is following:

`Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [name] => xxxNAMExxx [id] => XXXXNUMBERSXXXXX ) )` and `data: xxxNAMExxx`

(I obviously hidden my ID and real name)

**Question is**: Why can't I get things like `email` or `user_hometown` in my `$userNode` array, even if I specified those in `$permissions` ([ref](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions))? I can get `name` because its set, but besides this and `id`, there's nothing more...

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing Declarative Fields in the API call:

```
$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,email,likes,hometown');
```

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4